# The document bytes are not retrieved properly from the plugin in web platform

Tags: flutter, web, plugins

Please run the sample in a web browser.
Click on the button in the output screen.
In the console, you may notice that the byte length is not being retrieved properly.

[Sample](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/flutter_pdf_app.1_(1)-599921857)

Expected results

[image: Expected result]

Actual results

[image: Actual result]